# Auto-suggest title for links in posts/comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, posts

I'm a bit of a lazy fellow when it comes to adding links to posts/comments on StackExchange sites. I've been participating in some Area51/SE sites lately where I find it particularly hand to reference source materials (books, articles) very frequently. Even on StackOverflow itself, I think the frequency of linking to developer resources is quite high.

Hemce, my proposal is to provide some sort of auto-suggest/auto-complete/keyboard-shortcut feature that allows you to paste a plain old URL and have it formatted into `[link url](title of page at URL)`. Where the title used is the standard HTML-defined title. This could possibly be implemented client-side using JavaScript AJAX to avoid server load.

In any case, a feature along these lines would save me a good deal of time. I feel it would also encourage better referencing/citing by all users on most SE sites, especially in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It already does this when linking to questions on SO.

For links to other sites, the problem is that the standard page title is unfortunately usually meaningless.  Way to many sites don't bother updating the page title to have any bearing on it's actual content.

Combine that with no real way of determining if the foreign title has bearing and you end up in a situation where it is better that SO doesn't try and figure it out for you... except for stackexchange sites.

Comment: I would argue that the standard page title is far from meaningless on most other sites. It's a *very* handy default at least, in my view. :-) Thanks for the SO-related info anyway.